# Join to campfire room with curl

Tags: api, rest, curl, campfire

I try to join in campfire room with campfire [room api](https://github.com/37signals/campfire-api/blob/master/sections/rooms.md) with curl.

I try:

`curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -i --user my_token:my_password https://camp111.campfirenow.com/room/test_room/join.json`

I got response:

`<html><body>You are being <a href="https://camp111.campfirenow.com/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

How can i correctly join to campfire room with curl?

Thank you.

Comment: btw you can use dummy password(X instead of my_password) with token for all methods except on /users/me.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace test_room with your digital `roomId` and also you have to specify at least empty `-d` parameter to set POST method in headers and you may omit `-i` and `-H`  parameters for the join request.

Remember that you can join to room invited accounts only.